# Is this article about the SMASH hypothesis a fair assessment?

Tags: dark-matter, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, baryogenesis, axion

New Scientist is gushing as usual about a [new development](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2110591-physics-tweak-solves-five-of-the-biggest-problems-in-one-go/) in physics. This one, called SMASH, looks truly interesting, though.

Apparently it's a small extension to the Standard Model that explains "dark matter, neutrino oscillations, baryogenesis, inflation and the strong CP problem", and is testable in the near future.

Google searches ultimately lead back to New Scientist and arxiv.org.

I looked at the paper's [abstract on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05414v1) and it seems to match what the article is saying. Unfortunately the paper itself is beyond this layman. Can someone give a thumbs-up or thumbs-down on the article? Is the hypothesis interesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really not totally a new hypothesis. They are taking some model extensions to the SM that were proposed in other papers to add Beyond the SM particles that would account for inflation, baryogenesis and dark matter. None of those have been detected, though they remain possible. What they do that is new is that they show that those new particles, in combination, would explain all those cosmologically unanswered issues.

They say that those effects and some of the particles may be detected in the next generation of CMB and axion detection experiments. It is interesting to know that, but no real new findings. Note that they point out that one of the set of particles happen because a symmetry breaking at $10^{11}$ GeV. That's $10^8$ TEV. The LHC is at around 10 TeV now, pretty far from being of any use for any accelerator experiment at the higher energies.

Yes, it is one of the possible new findings on a way forward in Beyond the SM.

Note that none of what they bring up has anything to say about Dark Energy, which still would need the cosmological constant with no clear reason for it (but needed to explain the Cosmological expansion acceleration, and is about 70% of the universe mass-energy density).